# C# script issues - string not separating properly into list?

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to load a plain text file into a `List(List(string))`, separated by either`EndTextBlock` (into the List) or `EndDialogBlock` (into the `List(List)`). Each Dialog block can be different lengths.

I have a simple read file line that reads every line of my txt file and adds each line as a new item in `TXTDialogFileList`. The code below is where I am trying to sort out that raw data and make the double List.

```
//loop to increment the list's counter
for (int i = 0; i < TXTDialogFileList.Count; i++)   
{
    DialogBlock = new List<string> ();

    bool NextRun = false;
    do
    {   //do-while loop to merge multiple lines into 1 slot in the list
        //DialogBlock = new List<string> ();

        if ( (i + 1) < TXTDialogFileList.Count)
        {
            if (   TXTDialogFileList[i+1] == "EndDialogBlock" 
                || TXTDialogFileList[i+1] == "EndTextBlock"     )
            {
                //line break removal to next in list
                //TXTDialogFileList[i+1].Remove(TXTFileList[i+1]);
                //print (TXTDialogFileList[i]);
                //print (RunCounter + " " + (i + 1));

                DialogBlock.Add (TXTDialogFileList[i]);

                //DialogConvertedList[RunCounter].Add (TXTDialogFileList[i]);
                if (TXTDialogFileList[i+1] == "EndDialogBlock")
                {
                    //only increment counter for converted list if it's end dialog
                    RunCounter ++;  
                    DialogConvertedList.Add (DialogBlock);
                    NextRun = false;
                }
                else if (TXTDialogFileList[i+1] == "EndTextBlock")
                {
                    DialogConvertedList.Add (DialogBlock);
                    NextRun = true;
                    //DialogBlock = new List<string>();
                }
                TXTDialogFileList.Remove(TXTDialogFileList[i+1]);
            }

            else
            {
                //merging next line to current line in list (line break in between)
                TXTDialogFileList[i] = TXTDialogFileList[i] 
                                        + '\n' + TXTDialogFileList[i+1];
                TXTDialogFileList.Remove(TXTDialogFileList[i+1]);
                NextRun = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //no more lines in file
            NextRun = false;
        }
    } while ((NextRun == true));
}
```

There's a problem in the code and I can't seem to find out how to fix it. Right now what I end up with is: `Textbox1` outputs text1, `Textbox2` outputs text1 + text2, `Textbox3` outputs text1 + text2 + text3, and so forth.

I tried declaring `DialogBlock` as a new List again after adding the list to the `ConvertedList` list, but that just ended up making everything after `text1` disappear completely.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see if I understood your goal. Here is my sample text:

```
The first line of text
The second line of text
EndTextBlock
The third line of text
The fourth line of text
EndTextBlock
The fifth line of text
The sixth line of text
EndDialogBlock
The seventh line of text
The eight line of text
EndTextBlock
EndDialogBlock
The ninth line of text
The tenth line of text
EndTextBlock
The eleventh line of text
The twelfth line of text
EndDialogBlock
```

Below is some code to process it. I have kept your variable name `TXTDialogFileList` though I think it may be a misleading one. I changed many of the others as they refer to elements outside the code snippet:

```
    List<String> TXTDialogFileList = new List<String>();

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"sampletext");
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        TXTDialogFileList.Add(sr.ReadLine());
    }
    sr.Close(); 

    var currentList = new List<String>();   
    var resultList = new List<List<String>>();  
    var currentLines = "";

    foreach (String line in TXTDialogFileList)
    {
        switch (line)
        {
            case "EndTextBlock":
                currentList.Add(currentLines);
                currentLines="";
                break;
            case "EndDialogBlock":
                if (currentLines.Length > 0) currentList.Add(currentLines); // assuming implicit EndTextBlock before EndDialogBlock
                resultList.Add(new List<String>(currentList)); // list<string> added by reference so make sure it is a new list before it is cleared on next line
                currentList.Clear(); 
                currentLines="";
                break;
            default:
                currentLines += line + "\n";
                break;  
        }
    }

    // Output the List<List<String>> to show results are correct
    foreach (var textBlock in resultList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start DialogBlock");
        foreach(var text in textBlock)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start TextBlock");
            Console.Write(text);
        }
    }

    Console.Read();
```

Even if I have misunderstood your exact goal I think the things you need to watch out for are:

- Use `foreach` loops. Much easier to read.
- Use a `switch` statement. Much easier to read and I suspect suitable 
  for your needs.
- Be careful of adding a `List<String>` to a `List`. When you modify
  the list you add later, you are modifying the added list.    In other
  words they are added by Reference.

Comment: Looks like that worked exactly as needed, thanks! I did not know that reference bit - figured it'd just copy the data over and call it a day. That must be the problem for my version, but yours is really condensed! Thanks a lot.